# Display large background on parent div when hover on a child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Title might not be so descriptive, sorry. What I'm trying to accomplish is to make  a gallery that has 9 different images. What I want to do is that when you hover one of these images, a big version of the image is shown as the background of all the images.

I got the following codepen: http://codepen.io/michaelc_1990/pen/NNyqJb

As it is now, when you hover over one of the images, it shows an image. This image however doesn't change depending on what image is hovered. Is there a way to select the background of the div hovered, and place that as the background? Or is there a smarter way than what I'm doing?

My html structure looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="one"></td>
    <td id="two"></td>
    <td id="three"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="four"></td>
    <td id="five"></td>
    <td id="six"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="seven"></td>
    <td id="eight"></td>
    <td id="nine"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to get the url of the image and insert it into the table below?

```css
table {
  background: url('') no-repeat center top / cover;
}
```

I'm setting the background images with css, like this:

```css
#one {
  background: url('image-url-here') no-repeat center / cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do by adding this line:

```
document.querySelector('table').style.backgroundImage = window.getComputedStyle(e.target).backgroundImage;
```

In this line you get the current background image and set it to the table.

```js
var table = document.querySelector("table");
var tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("td"));

tds.forEach(a => a.addEventListener("mouseover", changeBg));
var small = true;
function changeBg(e) {
  if (small) {
    tds.forEach(a => a.style.opacity = 0);
    small = false;
  } else {
    tds.forEach(a => a.style.opacity = 1);
    small = true;
  }

  document.querySelector('table').style.backgroundImage = window.getComputedStyle(e.target).backgroundImage;
}
```

```css
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  margin: auto;
  background: url('http://burninbrains.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Cool-Or-Fool-Donald-Trump.png') no-repeat center top / cover;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 66.66px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

#one{
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1458724338480-79bc7a8352e4?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=1000&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1925') no-repeat center / cover;
}

#two{
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1457369804613-52c61a468e7d?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=1000&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1925') no-repeat center / cover;
}

#three{
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1456318019777-ccdc4d5b2396?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=1000&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1925') no-repeat center / cover;
}

#four{
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1455098934982-64c622c5e066?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=8eae6295f7c95422742a20ca784bffc0') no-repeat center / cover;
}

#five{
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1454047637795-79e3325dfa0e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=8e20ceb0363ab9c8148ab76ce5979f2d') no-repeat center / cover;
}

#six{
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1440227537815-f4476b789291?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=f936b619523b02905c71d87361060713') no-repeat center / cover;
}

#seven{
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1428189923803-e9801d464d76?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=467ee7b8a091aa5cb8bc9b496aada853') no-repeat center / cover;
}

#eight{
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1422393462206-207b0fbd8d6b?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=ac3dcc36ecded066d44617b34b3e940b') no-repeat center / cover;
}

#nine{
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1415822138156-fd0cd874335a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=2714a0f2bf8f3fe5108dd295efeca084') no-repeat center / cover;
}
```

```html
<h3>Click Don</h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="one"></td>
    <td id="two"></td>
    <td id="three"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="four"></td>
    <td id="five"></td>
    <td id="six"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="seven"></td>
    <td id="eight"></td>
    <td id="nine"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsbin.com/xemisoz/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery as such. (Make sure you use jQuery. You will have to DL jquery and inset it to your html,php,jsp or wahtever.)

```
var URL = something;
$('#childElementIDComesHere').on('mouseover', function(){
    $('#parentElementIDComesHere').css('background','url(" + URL + ") no-repeat center / cover');
});
```